# How to use a custom kernel in Matlab like chi square

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, svm

I want to use a chi squared kernel with svmtrain in matlab but I can not find an implementation on internet. Does any one know how to make a custom MATLAB kernel for the matlab function svmtrain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass an anonymous function `@(x,y) 1 - sum((x - y).^2 ./ (x + y) / 2)` as the kernel_function argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using precomputed kernels, an excellent example and a more detailed explanation can be found in this question: [using precomputed kernels with libsvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715138/using-precomputed-kernels-with-libsvm)