# Prepare my data for training in SVM libsvm matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, svm, libsvm

I am still confused with so many answers that are not comprehensive in how to prepare the data for the Libsvm in mat-lab and what is the exact requirements to finish training

I have the following data and I need to know what is the next step ( my data in excel now)

```
lable   words   total_char  domain len  Ratio   digit   dash    Jaccard  String 
-1         0       0             11     0.0000      0      0    0.3444  uvcaylkgdpg
-1         0       0              8     0.0000      0      0    0.2707  yqdqyntx
-1         1       2              10    0.2000      0      0    0.1761  vzcocljtfi
-1         0       0              8     0.0000      0      0    0.1919  wojpnhwk
-1         0       0              9     0.0000      0      0    0.3475  plrjgcjzf

 1         1       4             6      0.6667      0      0    0.4264  google
 1         4       14            8      1.7500      0      0    0.3444  facebook
 1         4       13            7      1.8571      0      0    0.2707  youtube
 1         1       3             5      0.6000      0      0    0.1761  yahoo
 1         1       3             5      0.6000      0      0    0.1919  baidu
 1         0       0             9      0.0000      0      0    0.3475  wikipedia
```

this is a portion of my data that i need to train the classifier

now i would know what is the next step in mat lab to do so
I have done the following
installing Libsvm and it is working fine
I need to know how i can get the best result and the correct tuning in order to plot the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next part as you said is to train the classifier or create the model for future classification.That is to find the parameters for SVM model.You can use `svmtrain` in LIBSVM to train the model.

For example,

```
model = svmtrain(TrainLabel, TrainVec, '-c 1 -g 0.00154');
```

The parameters you need to decide is of c and gamma.

The step after that would be do prediction which you need to `svmpredict`.

Example:

```
[predict_label, accuracy, dec_values] = svmpredict(TestLabel, TestVec, model);
```

Hope it helps you to continue with your process.

Read the answer for this qn by me: [Retraining after Cross Validation with libsvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047459/retraining-after-cross-validation-with-libsvm)

Comment: good thank you for the answer, is there any common practice to tune c and gamma ?

Comment: edited my question. do have the look at the qn posted..