# Selecting SVM parameters using cross validation and F1-scores

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification, svm, cross-validation

I need to keep track of the F1-scores while tuning C & Sigma in SVM,
For example the following code keeps track of the Accuracy, I need to change it to F1-Score but I was not able to do that…….

```
%# read some training data
[labels,data] = libsvmread('./heart_scale');

%# grid of parameters
folds = 5;
[C,gamma] = meshgrid(-5:2:15, -15:2:3);

%# grid search, and cross-validation
cv_acc = zeros(numel(C),1);
    for i=1:numel(C)
cv_acc(i) = svmtrain(labels, data, ...
                sprintf('-c %f -g %f -v %d', 2^C(i), 2^gamma(i), folds));
end

%# pair (C,gamma) with best accuracy
[~,idx] = max(cv_acc);

%# now you can train you model using best_C and best_gamma
best_C = 2^C(idx);
best_gamma = 2^gamma(idx);
%# ...
```

I have seen the following two links

[Retraining after Cross Validation with libsvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047459/retraining-after-cross-validation-with-libsvm/9049225#9049225)

[10 fold cross-validation in one-against-all SVM (using LibSVM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14024740/10-fold-cross-validation-in-one-against-all-svm-using-libsvm)

I do understand that I have to first find the best C and gamma/sigma parameters over the training data, then use these two values to do a LEAVE-ONE-OUT crossvalidation classification experiment,
So what I want now is to first do a grid-search for tuning C & sigma.
Please I would prefer to use MATLAB-SVM and not LIBSVM. 
Below is my code for  LEAVE-ONE-OUT crossvalidation classification.

```
... clc
 clear all
close all
a = load('V1.csv');
X = double(a(:,1:12));
Y = double(a(:,13));
% train data
datall=[X,Y];
A=datall;
n = 40;
ordering = randperm(n);
B = A(ordering, :);  
good=B; 
input=good(:,1:12);
target=good(:,13);
CVO = cvpartition(target,'leaveout',1);  
cp = classperf(target);                      %# init performance tracker
svmModel=[];
for i = 1:CVO.NumTestSets                                %# for each fold
trIdx = CVO.training(i);              
teIdx = CVO.test(i);                   
%# train an SVM model over training instances

svmModel = svmtrain(input(trIdx,:), target(trIdx), ...
       'Autoscale',true, 'Showplot',false, 'Method','ls', ...
      'BoxConstraint',0.1, 'Kernel_Function','rbf', 'RBF_Sigma',0.1);
%# test using test instances
pred = svmclassify(svmModel, input(teIdx,:), 'Showplot',false);
%# evaluate and update performance object
cp = classperf(cp, pred, teIdx); 
end
%# get accuracy
accuracy=cp.CorrectRate*100
sensitivity=cp.Sensitivity*100
specificity=cp.Specificity*100
PPV=cp.PositivePredictiveValue*100
NPV=cp.NegativePredictiveValue*100
%# get confusion matrix
%# columns:actual, rows:predicted, last-row: unclassified instances
cp.CountingMatrix
recallP = sensitivity;
recallN = specificity;
precisionP = PPV;
precisionN = NPV;
f1P = 2*((precisionP*recallP)/(precisionP + recallP));
f1N = 2*((precisionN*recallN)/(precisionN + recallN));
aF1 = ((f1P+f1N)/2);
```

i have changed the code
but i making some mistakes and i am getting errors,

```
a = load('V1.csv');
X = double(a(:,1:12));
Y = double(a(:,13));
% train data
datall=[X,Y];
A=datall;
n = 40;
ordering = randperm(n);
B = A(ordering, :);  
good=B; 
inpt=good(:,1:12);
target=good(:,13);
k=10;
cvFolds = crossvalind('Kfold', target, k);   %# get indices of 10-fold CV
cp = classperf(target);                      %# init performance tracker
svmModel=[];
for i = 1:k 
    testIdx = (cvFolds == i);    %# get indices of test    instances
trainIdx = ~testIdx;   
C = 0.1:0.1:1; 
S = 0.1:0.1:1; 
fscores = zeros(numel(C), numel(S)); %// Pre-allocation
for c = 1:numel(C)   
for s = 1:numel(S)
    vals = crossval(@(XTRAIN, YTRAIN, XVAL, YVAL)(fun(XTRAIN, YTRAIN, XVAL, YVAL, C(c), S(c))),inpt(trainIdx,:),target(trainIdx));
    fscores(c,s) = mean(vals);
end
end
 end

[cbest, sbest] = find(fscores == max(fscores(:)));
C_final = C(cbest);
S_final = S(sbest);
```

.......

and the function.....

```
.....
function fscore = fun(XTRAIN, YTRAIN, XVAL, YVAL, C, S)
svmModel = svmtrain(XTRAIN, YTRAIN, ...
   'Autoscale',true, 'Showplot',false, 'Method','ls', ...
  'BoxConstraint', C, 'Kernel_Function','rbf', 'RBF_Sigma', S);

   pred = svmclassify(svmModel, XVAL, 'Showplot',false);

   cp = classperf(YVAL, pred)
   %# get accuracy
    accuracy=cp.CorrectRate*100
    sensitivity=cp.Sensitivity*100
    specificity=cp.Specificity*100
    PPV=cp.PositivePredictiveValue*100
    NPV=cp.NegativePredictiveValue*100
    %# get confusion matrix
    %# columns:actual, rows:predicted, last-row: unclassified instances
    cp.CountingMatrix
    recallP = sensitivity;
    recallN = specificity;
    precisionP = PPV;
    precisionN = NPV;
    f1P = 2*((precisionP*recallP)/(precisionP + recallP));
    f1N = 2*((precisionN*recallN)/(precisionN + recallN));
    fscore = ((f1P+f1N)/2);

    end
```

Comment: Do you want to use Matlab's stats toolbox or machine learning? Either way the code will be totally different to your libsvm example. Please try code it in matlab first: http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/classificationsvm.crossval.html or atleast post your matlab SVM code where you arbitrarily set the parameters to a single vale (i.e. no tuning via cross validation)

Comment: this is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047459/retraining-after-cross-validation-with-libsvm/9049225#9049225

Comment: So that code is for libsvm. You need to first show us what your NON-libsvm code looks like. Just post the simple code without the cross validation (i.e. grid-search) stuff. But as a clue, you'd probably want to use this function: http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/crossval.html

Comment: i have edited the code and added the MATLAB code thank you

Answer (score 1):

So basically you want to take this line of yours:

```
svmModel = svmtrain(input(trIdx,:), target(trIdx), ...
       'Autoscale',true, 'Showplot',false, 'Method','ls', ...
      'BoxConstraint',0.1, 'Kernel_Function','rbf', 'RBF_Sigma',0.1);
```

put it in a loop that varies your `'BoxConstraint'` and `'RBF_Sigma'` parameters and then uses [`crossval`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/crossval.html) to output the f1-score for that iterations combination of parameters.

You can use a single for-loop exactly like in your libsvm code example (i.e. using `meshgrid` and `1:numel()`, this is probably faster) or a nested for-loop. I'll use a nested loop so that you have both approaches:

```
C = [0.001, 0.003, 0.01, 0.03, 0.1, 0.3, 1, 3, 10, 30, 100, 300] %// you must choose your own set of values for the parameters that you want to test. You can either do it this way by explicitly typing out a list
S = 0:0.1:1 %// or you can do it this way using the : operator
fscores = zeros(numel(C), numel(S)); %// Pre-allocation
for c = 1:numel(C)   
    for s = 1:numel(S)
        vals = crossval(@(XTRAIN, YTRAIN, XVAL, YVAL)(fun(XTRAIN, YTRAIN, XVAL, YVAL, C(c), S(c)),input(trIdx,:),target(trIdx));
        fscores(c,s) = mean(vals);
    end
end

%// Then establish the C and S that gave you the bet f-score. Don't forget that c and s are just indexes though!
[cbest, sbest] = find(fscores == max(fscores(:)));
C_final = C(cbest);
S_final = S(sbest);
```

Now we just have to define the function `fun`. The docs have this to say about `fun`:

> fun is a function handle to a function with two inputs, the training
>   subset of X, XTRAIN, and the test subset of X, XTEST, as follows:
>
> testval = fun(XTRAIN,XTEST) Each time it is called, fun should use
>   XTRAIN to fit a model, then return some criterion testval computed on
>   XTEST using that fitted model.

So `fun` needs to:

- output a single f-score
- take as input a training and testing set for X and Y. *Note that these are both subsets of your actual training set! Think of them more like a training and validation SUBSET of your training set. Also note that crossval will split these sets up for you!*
- Train a classifier on the training subset (using your current `C` and `S` parameters from your loop)
- RUN your new classifier on the test (or validation rather) subset
- Compute and output a performance metric (in your case you want the f1-score)

You'll notice that `fun` can't take any extra parameters which is why I've wrapped it in an anonymous function so that we can pass the current `C` and `S` values in. (i.e. all that `@(...)(fun(...))` stuff above. That's just a trick to "convert" our six parameter `fun` into the 4 parameter one required by `crossval`.

```
function fscore = fun(XTRAIN, YTRAIN, XVAL, YVAL, C, S)

   svmModel = svmtrain(XTRAIN, YTRAIN, ...
       'Autoscale',true, 'Showplot',false, 'Method','ls', ...
      'BoxConstraint', C, 'Kernel_Function','rbf', 'RBF_Sigma', S);

   pred = svmclassify(svmModel, XVAL, 'Showplot',false);

   CP = classperf(YVAL, pred)

   fscore = ... %// You can do this bit the same way you did earlier
end
```

Comment: No problem - please let me know if you find any errors!

Comment: Firstly why did you change it to use `...,inpt,target`? This is an anonymous function and those variables are not variables in your workspace... Secondly the error sounds like it's complaining that you have all the same number in `target(trIdx)`.

Comment: `XTRAIN, YTRAIN, XVAL, YVAL` get generated by `crossval`. `crossval` needs you to supply it with *your* training data though (which it will then split into smaller training and validation sets itself)

Comment: .....I have changed it to......vals = crossval(@(XTRAIN, YTRAIN, XVAL, YVAL)(fun(XTRAIN, YTRAIN, XVAL, YVAL, C(c), S(c))),input,target);............input is a 40X12 dataset and target is a 40X1 data-target with two classes 0s and 1s.......but MATLAB still says Ground truth must have at least two classes.

Comment: @Wasnuga So firstly, undo that change as you are still going to need your test set later. The problem I'm sure is with `classperf` (in future please post the entire error). You're just going to have to calculate f1-score without it (which really isn't hard). If you can't manage this (after seriously trying) please ask it as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

I found the only problem with `target(trainIdx)`. It's a row vector so I just replaced `target(trainIdx)` with `target(trainIdx)` which is a column vector.