# Cross validation with KNN classifier in Matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, classification, cross-validation

I am trying to extend [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34724463/example-of-10-fold-cross-validation-with-neural-network-classification-in-matlab) to knn classifier:

```
load fisheriris;

% // convert species to double
isnum = cellfun(@isnumeric,species);
result = NaN(size(species));
result(isnum) = [species{isnum}];

% // Crossvalidation
vals = crossval(@(XTRAIN, YTRAIN, XTEST, YTEST)fun_knn(XTRAIN, YTRAIN, XTEST, YTEST), meas, result);
```

the `fun_knn` funcion is:

```
function testval = fun_knn(XTRAIN, YTRAIN, XTEST, YTEST)
    yknn = knnclassify(XTEST, XTRAIN, YTRAIN);      
    [~,classNet] = max(yknn,[],2);
    [~,classTest] = max(YTEST,[],2);
    [~,classTest] = find(YTEST);    
    cp = classperf(classTest, classNet);        
    testval = cp.CorrectRate;
end
```

I receive this error: `Ground truth must have at least two classes.`

Seems like the problem is that `knnclassify` produces empty result.I would like to use more modern funcitons like `fitcknn`, however I dont know how can I use training and task input for this function.

Comment: How does YTRAIN look like just before knnclassify is called? "Ground truth must have at least two classes." seems to indicate that something is wrong with it (e.g. wrong shape or only zeros).