# Why I only get one column of probability estimates for two classes in libsvm?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification, svm, libsvm

I copied the code from [Multi-class classification in libsvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9041753/multi-class-classification-in-libsvm) to get the probability estimates for each class.

However, I have an error in that my probability estimates p only has one column when there should be two columns. I checked my model and it states there are two classes (model.nr_class = 2) and (model.Label = [0;1]).

Can someone explain?

My probability estimates range from -0.35 to 1.2057 so they are not between 0 and 1.
Giving the option -b 0 and -b 1 returns the same result.

Comment: if there are two classes and you have the probability of class A, isn't p(B|x) just 1 - p(A|x)?

Comment: Oh, I figured it out. You have to give -b 1 to both training and testing to get two columns. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you miss the `-b` option in training. Check [libsvm documentation](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/).

Answer (score 0):

as you are having 2 classes, its clear that if the prob of class A is `0.xxxx` then prob of another class is `1-0.xxxx`, that you can clearly calculate...