# Multi-class classification for large database (matlab)

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification, svm, libsvm

Can you suggest any implementation (matlab) of Multi-class classification algorithm for large database, I tried libsvm it's good except for large database and for the liblinear I can't use it for the multi classification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use liblinear for multi class classification, you can use [one vs all](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification#One-vs.-rest) technique. For more information Look at [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9041753/multi-class-classification-in-libsvm)

But if you have large database then use of SVM is not recommended. As Run time complexity of SVM is O(N * N * m)

N = number of samples in data 
m = number of features in data

So, alternatively You can use Neural Network. You can start with nntool available in MATLAB.